# Localstorage & Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, local-storage

I need help with a issue related to localstorage.

**Scenario**
I am developing a web app of quotes which needs a bookmark system to save the quotes more liked by user. To sort out this issue, I have developed a jquery content which generates dynamically a div through a "onclick" function (see below):

```js
function crearLink1() {
  jQuery('<div class="item"><a>Elemento creado dinámicamente 1</a><button class="eliminar"></button></div>').find('a').attr('href', '#').end().appendTo('#bookmarks');
}

function crearLink2() {
  jQuery('<div class="item"><a>Elemento creado dinámicamente 2</a><button class="eliminar"></button></div>').find('a').attr('href', '#').end().appendTo('#bookmarks');
}

function crearLink3() {
  jQuery('<div class="item"><a>Elemento creado dinámicamente 3</a><button class="eliminar"></button></div>').find('a').attr('href', '#').end().appendTo('#bookmarks');
}

function crearLink4() {
  jQuery('<div class="item"><a>Elemento creado dinámicamente 4</a><button class="eliminar"></button></div>').find('a').attr('href', '#').end().appendTo('#bookmarks');
}



$(document).on('click', '.eliminar', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
#bookmarks {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: rgba(236, 233, 233, 1.00);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.item {
  height: 30px;
  font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: rgba(229, 226, 140, 1.00);
}
.eliminar {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: rgba(222, 28, 31, 1.00);
  right: 5px;
}
.quote {
  width: 100%;
}
.titulo {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.parrafo {
  font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(77, 76, 184, 1.00);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bookmarks</title>


</head>

<body>

  <div id="bookmarks"></div>

  <div class="quote">
    <h1 class="titulo">Título de la cita</h1>
    <p class="parrafo">kjfkl jgdfsklhsdfjkbsjl hauñ g hgauñigh erajkh uh ad.jk hñhakjh gulhrj sjhg slkghdsjkh slh gajk gh iñhsjk jldfsh grñkj s hñihg sjdh</p>
    <button class="btn" onclick="crearLink1();"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="quote">
    <h1 class="titulo">Título de la cita</h1>
    <p class="parrafo">kjfkl jgdfsklhsdfjkbsjl hauñ g hgauñigh erajkh uh ad.jk hñhakjh gulhrj sjhg slkghdsjkh slh gajk gh iñhsjk jldfsh grñkj s hñihg sjdh</p>
    <button class="btn" onclick="crearLink2();"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="quote">
    <h1 class="titulo">Título de la cita</h1>
    <p class="parrafo">kjfkl jgdfsklhsdfjkbsjl hauñ g hgauñigh erajkh uh ad.jk hñhakjh gulhrj sjhg slkghdsjkh slh gajk gh iñhsjk jldfsh grñkj s hñihg sjdh</p>
    <button class="btn" onclick="crearLink3();"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="quote">
    <h1 class="titulo">Título de la cita</h1>
    <p class="parrafo">kjfkl jgdfsklhsdfjkbsjl hauñ g hgauñigh erajkh uh ad.jk hñhakjh gulhrj sjhg slkghdsjkh slh gajk gh iñhsjk jldfsh grñkj s hñihg sjdh</p>
    <button class="btn" onclick="crearLink4();"></button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Problem**
But this code has a problem: It does not save when you either close or refresh, so I decided to use "localstorage" to save the content generated , but I am not able to find the way to implement it into js to generate a bookmark pages into my web app.
Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Storing content in the localstorage is easy.

Storing a json/array:

```
localStorage.setItem("quotes", JSON.stringify({
 quote1: "This is a quote."
}));
```

Receiving:

```
var quotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("quotes"));
```

*Why would i use stringify and parse?*
Because localStorage does not accept json, only strings, integers and booleans.

Comment: Thanks!  But I think I made a mistake with the question...  The correct question is How can I store the content dynamically generated(divs with its links)?  Thanks again